# Seeking a merge algorithm that preserves duplicates

Tags: algorithm, merge, duplicates

I need an algorithm for a somewhat unusual type of merge. I'm sure I can create one, but I suspect there is more than one way to do it, and I'm not sure the algorithm I create will be the best. I wonder whether a well designed one is already known.

In the following examples, words like tree, duck, hat,... represent objects of an arbitrary type. They could be words, records, messages, etc. The subscripts (L) and (R) represent origin ("left" or "right") *only*. tree(L) and tree(R) are identical by definition, except for the sources they occur in.

In the results, '===' means "is equivalent to." For example, "tree(L)===tree(R)" means that "tree" in the left source is equivalent to "tree" in the right source. "duck(L)===" means that "duck" in the left source has no equivalent in the right source. "===sun(R)" means that "sun" in the right source has no equivalent in the left source.

Given these sources, the algorithm produces these results:

```
Left:   tree(L), duck(L), hat(L), peg(L)
Right:  tree(R), hat(R), sun(R), peg(R)
Result: tree(L)===tree(R), duck(L)===, hat(L)===hat(R), ===sun(R), peg(L)===peg(R)
```

Order is significant, and the and given a choice, the algorithm finds an equivalent in the right source for the object nearest the beginning of the left:

```
Left:   tree(L), duck(L), peg(L), hat(L)
Right:  tree(R), hat(R), peg(R)
Result: tree(L)===tree(R), duck(L)===, ===hat(R), peg(L)===peg(R), hat(L)
Not:    tree(L)===tree(R), duck(L)===, peg(L)===, hat(L)===hat(R), ===peg(R)
```

Any number of objects may occur consecutively in one source but not the other, so a simple look-ahead approach won't work:

```
Left:   tree(L), wig(L), yolk(L)
Right:  tree(R), cap(R), jet(R), map(R), fox(R),... ink(R), yolk(R)
Result: tree(L)===tree(R), wig(L)===, ===cap(R), ===jet(R), ===map(R), ===fox(R),... ===ink(R), yolk(L)===yolk(R)
```

Now the weird part: the algorithm must preserve duplicates:

```
Left:   tree(L), rim(L), lamp(L)
Right:  tree(R), rim(R), rim(R), lamp(R)
Result: tree(L)===tree(R), rim(L)===rim(R), ===rim(R), lamp(L)===lamp(R)
```

Does anyone know of a well designed algorithm that works this way?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question right, you are looking for some kind of greedy algorithm. 
The following example shows why the process is greedy, but is also destined to see whether I understood the question right.

```
Left:   A B C D E F G H I J
Right:  A J C D E F G H I
Result: A=A B= C= D= E= F= G= H= I= J=J =C =D =E =F =G =H =I
```

The `J(L)` element needs to be mapped with the `J(R)` element ("the algorithm finds an equivalent in the right source for the object nearest the beginning of the left"), therefore all other matchings which could be possible are no longer possible.

This answer does not yet provide an answer to your question, please confirm that the example solution is right first.

Additionally, it is not clear how exactly the merging should take place:

```
Left:          A B C D E F
Right:         A G H I J F
Possibility 1: A=A B= C= D= E= =G =H =I =J F=F
Possibility 2: A=A =G =H =I =J B= C= D= E= F=F
Possibility 3: A=A B= =G C= =H D= =I E= =J F=F
... many other possibilities
```

---

I don't think such a specific algorithm already exists.

Depending on the input size, a simple O(n^2) algorithm would be easiest, but a better algorithm may be needed if the input size is too big.

For each entry in the right list scan whether a matching entry exists in the left list, scanning only entries right to the last matched element. 
If such an entry is found, it can be matched to the element in the right list (after inserting all previous remaining entries as unmatched). If no matching element is found, insert the element from the right list as unmatched and continue with the next element.

This can simply be implemented with three pointers: current element in the right list, last matched element in the left list and currently searched element in the left list (always going from last matched element to the end of the list, unless a matching element is found sooner).

Comment: You understood it right. In the case where you asked for clarification, the different possibilities were equally acceptable.

Comment: @JonathanSachs: updated the answer, depending on how many elements you are merging, this is probably the quickest solution. For big input sizes, it isn't. I described the algorithm only vaguely, if you have problems understanding it, let me know.